# I need to use shrinkMode = "strict"

Tags: android, shrinkresources

I need to use `shrinkMode(strict)`.

I created a file  `keep.xml` in category `res/raw/keep.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources                          
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"            
tools:shrinkMode="strict" />
```

This does not work. But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Over flow. I realise that English is not your first language, but please can you edit your question to include the error messages you get

Comment: I don't have error. I  used shrinkMode and shrinkResources  , but my APK size doesn't decrease.

Comment: Could you check my answer ?Thank you .@Adept

Answer (score 0):

You should set **`shrinkResources true`** in your `build.gradle(app)` .

And create file like `res/raw/keep.xml`

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```